# Automatically find start and end of the work week in a Google Spreadsheet

Tags: google-sheets

My work week goes from Monday to Sunday and I need to find a way to have 2 different cells automatically update based on =today() what the actual date of the start and end of the current work week is.

Is there a formula that can find this?

Similarly:

Is there also a similar method to automate the first and last days of the current month in different cells?

Thank you ahead of time for any assistance

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Assuming you're referencing a date in A1...

Start of the work week containing that date (assuming work week starts on Monday):

`=A1-WEEKDAY(A1;3)`

End of the work week:

`=A1-WEEKDAY(A1;3)+6`

Start of the month:

`=EOMONTH(A1;-1)+1`

End of the month:

`=EOMONTH(A1;0)`

I know this is Microsoft Excel documentation, but [this](http://office.microsoft.com/en-au/excel-help/eomonth-HP005209076.aspx) describes the EOMONTH function.

Comment: Beautiful - That worked great. Is there an easy way to also get the start and end dates of last month?

Comment: `=EOMONTH(A1;-2)+1` and `=EOMONTH(A1;-1)`. I will edit in EOMONTH documentation into the answer.